# Fastest way to order table by related table column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 tables    comments and images

I'm trying to order the comments that have an image first  and then comments without images.

I used this query below to solve this issue   but it's very slow on large data  it takes about 12 seconds

```
$data = Comment::withCount([
        'images' => function ($query) use ($shop)
        {
            $query->where('shop_name', $shop);

        },
    ])->where('shop_name', $shop)->orderBy('images_count', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

How can I improve the performance or is there any other way to get similar results in faster way ?

Comment: Can you post sample data for your tables ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in how Laravel makes `withCount()` work - it will generate something like this:

```
SELECT `comments`.*, 
   (SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM   `images` 
    WHERE  `comment_id`.`id` = `comments`.`id` 
           AND `images`.`shop_name` = 'your shop') AS `images_count` 
FROM   `comments` 
WHERE  `shop_name` = 'your_shop' 
ORDER  BY `images_count`
```

This will force MySQL to execute `count()` subquery for every comment of specified shop.

What you need to do here is to make this *correlated* subquery (that executes for every row) into an *independent* query (that executes only once) and then utilize joins to let MySQL pair it all up:

```
$imagesCountQuery = DB::table('comments')
    ->selectRaw('comments.id AS comment_id, COUNT(comments.id) AS images_count')
    ->join('images', 'images.comment_id', '=', 'comments.id') /* !!! */
    ->where('images.shop_name', '=', $shop)
    ->groupBy('comments.id');

$data = Comment::joinSub($imagesCountQuery, 'images_count_sub', function ($join) {
    $join->on('comments.id', '=', 'images_count_sub'.'comment_id'); /* !!! */
})->where('shop_name', $shop)->orderBy('images_count_sub.images_count', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

**!!!** - this lines should be modified to represent your comment's `images` relation. In this example I just assumed it was `hasMany` relation since you didn't point that out in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much , but joinSub  is not supported in laravel 5.5 or less  it started on 5.6 as I read      so I got an error  therefor I added it to laravel 5.5 and the query worked,  my query took 9.5s to finish  while your took 3.1s   which is 2 times faster then the old method  if I will wait if there anyway to reduce it more if not I will mark your answer since its better then what I could achieve

Comment: @ProgrammingSkills also make sure your tables utilize indices for the columns in joins/where clauses (`shop_name` columns would be a usual suspect). Maybe you can optimize it database side too to win a little bit time as well.

Comment: shop_name   is an index    I will check more  about it  thank you very much

Comment: I noticed today this is not working as withCount    it only adds relation and returns all comments with images only  while withCount   returns all comments and order them  by comments that has images.  but yours  removes all comments without images due the relation of joinSub

Comment: @ProgrammingSkills that's because `joinSub` does an inner join. If you need every record to be present you need to do outer join - in your case, use `leftJoinSub`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a hasMany relation in Comment model.

```
class Comment extends \Eloquent {  

        public function images()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Images', 'comment_id');
        } 
     }
```

Now you can use below query to fetch records.

```
$comments = Comments::with('images')->get()->sortBy(function($comment)
    {
        return $comment->images->count();
    });
```

Comment: He already has `images` relation since he is using it in `withCount()`. Your solution is to order collection PHP side after MySQL query is executed which is: a) bad practice b) not what he wanted.